# multiple java instances -Xms -Xmx

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I am running at the same computer a java game-server and a game-client

the game-client with

`java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp etc etc`

and the game-server

`java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar etc etc`

Computer Properties:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- 8GB RAM
- CPU i5-2500 @ 3.3GHz
- Intel HD Graphics

*Problem:* The game-client experience serious lags. At the game-server is also connected via LAN another player with no lag issues!

Has the problem of the lag to do anything with java virtual machine? Am I using one instance of machine or two?

Can I setup something different in order to optimize the performance?

I am thinking that the problem has to do with the fact that one machine is running and its max memory is not enough for both instances, but I do not really know how to solve that.

**Edit:** No app run out of memory.

---

***Solution**:*

1: 
Updated Java version from:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

to

```
java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

2: 
Changed the server properties in order to minimize requirements, this seems to be the main reason.

3:
Increased memory:
game-client with `java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp etc etc`
and the game-server `java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar etc etc`
Server runs at about 700MB now.

Comment: Each java application will be running under its own process. It is highly unlikely the lag is a result of the jvm itself. If either app is running out of memory you would probably see the errors.

Comment: Does the server much I/O? How much CPU does it need? (i.e., how is the cpu utilized when **only** the server with the other client is running?)

Comment: yes it runs on different processes, and CPU is at 30-25... I/O problem seems quite possible.

Comment: You could give visualVM a try to see everything is alright with your application . http://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has the problem of the lag to do anything with java virtual machine?

Possibly.  You haven't presented enough evidence to be sure one way or the other.

The puzzling thing is that the your client running on a different machine is not laggy.

> Am I using one instance of machine or two?

You are running two copies of `java` then you will have two JVMs.

> Can I setup something different in order to optimize the performance?

The answer is probably yes.  But you haven't provided enough information to allow us to make solid suggestions.

---

Lagginess can be caused by a number of things, including:

- A network with high latency.
- A JVM that has a heap that is too small.
- An application that is generating lots of garbage and triggering an excessive number of garbage collection.
- A mix of applications that is competing for resources; e.g. physical memory, CPU time or disc or network I/O time.

If you are going to get to the root cause of your problem, you will need to do some monitoring to figure out which of the above is the likely problem.  Use the task manager or whatever to check whether the system is CPU bound, short of memory, doing lots of disk or network stuff, etc.  Use VisualVM to see what is going on inside the JVMs.

---

Alternatively, you could try to fix with some totally unscientific "knob twiddling":

- try making the -Xms and -Xmx parameters the same (that may reduce lagginess at the start ...)
- try increasing the sizes of the JVMs' heaps; e.g. make them 2gb instead of 1gb
- try using a more recent version of Java
- try using a 64 bit JVM so that you can increase the heap size further
- try enabling the CMS or G1 collectors (depending on what version of JVM you are using).

If I knew more about what you were currently using, I could possibly give more concrete suggestions ...

Comment: +1 It finally worked! Thanks for mentioning all that possible reasons! Nice guide!

Answer (score 1):

You are using two java apps in same computer, resulting in 2 JVMs running.
For a 64 bit system with 8GB RAM, its recommended to use max 2GB(25% of Physical memory OR 75% of free physical memory up to 2 GB) for JVM for better performance.

You may have to look on JVM size adjustment. For better performance, Xms and Xmx size can be kept same with a max size bracket.

Assigning memory size to Heap is not the only area to think of. JVM uses more memory than just Heap. Others memory areas like Thread Stack, Method areas, Class Loader Subsystem, Native Method Stack etc. 
While both of the apps(game-server, game-client) are running, there is a chance of issue in memory management by OS between both apps, resulting in slowness. 
In that case, client app can be deployed in another core, if available.